# I have two list with different Type That I want Substract

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core

```
public async Task<GetUnusedPersonTypeFormsDto> GetUnusedForms()
{
    var unusedForms = await _personTypeManagementRepository
        .Query().GetAllAsync();

    var unusedFormsList = new List<GetUnusedPersonTypeFormsDto>();
    foreach (var item in unusedForms)
    {
        unusedFormsList.Add(new GetUnusedPersonTypeFormsDto
        {
           PersonTypeManagementId = item.Id,
           FormName = item.FormName
        });
    }

    var usedForm = await _personFormManagementRepository
        .Query()
        .Include(x => x.PersonTypeManagement)
        .GetAllAsync();

    var usedFormList = new List<GetUnusedPersonTypeFormsDto>();
    foreach (var item in usedForm)
    {
        usedFormList.Add(new GetUnusedPersonTypeFormsDto
        {
            PersonTypeManagementId = item.Id,
            FormName = item.PersonTypeManagement.FormName
        });
    }

    var resultList = unusedFormsList.Except(usedFormList);
    return (GetUnusedPersonTypeFormsDto)resultList;
}
```

this error occurred

> Unable to cast object of type 'd__81`1[IM.Application.DTOs.EMIC.PersonManagement.GetUnusedPersonTypeFormsDto]' to type 'IM.Application.DTOs.EMIC.PersonManagement.GetUnusedPersonTypeFormsDto'

Comment: The return type for the method should be something like `Task<IEnumerable<GetUnusedPersonTypeFormsDto>>` and then you should remove the cast in the last line.

Comment: `Except` [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) an `IEnumerable<T>` which obviously can't be casted to `T`. If you are sure that there will be at most 1 item in the returned collection then you should call `FirstOrDefault` on the `resultList`.